# Is there any method available to convert the html text to xhtml?

Tags: python, confluence

I am trying to store a table which is created by PrettyTable, in to confluence. I converted the data to html using the method PrettyTable.get_html_string(). I can store this data to local html file as per my requirement without any issues. However, when I tried to upload the data to the confluence using confluence.createPage(), I am getting errors related to XHTML parsing errors as createPage() accepts only XHTML and the content is not formatted properly. So, I would like to convert my HTML data to XHTML so I can push it to the confluence. Is there any method available to convert the pretty table data directly to the XHTML?

I tried to use PrettyTable._get_formatted_html_string(), but there is no proper information about which arguments should I give to that method from http://www.aplu.ch/classdoc/raspipylib/prettytable-pysrc.html#PrettyTable._get_formatted_html_string

Answer (score 0):

check the source html being created.  XHTML needs all tags closed which is most likely the problem:
   paragraph tag needs a close paragraph tag etc...

Comment: Hi Joe McKenna, thank you very much for your reply. Yes..that is the  issue I know. I am able to convert the content using online convertors like http://www.cruto.com/resources/code-generators/code-converters/html-to-xhtml.asp. I would like to know is there any python method available to that job form me.

Comment: Hi Joe McKenna, it was solved. Actually there is a method available in PrettyTable ```get_html_string(xhtml=True)```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method available in PrettyTable. Using the method get_html_string(xhtml=True) which automatically adds  as end tags. Here is the reference: http://www.aplu.ch/classdoc/raspipylib/prettytable-pysrc.html#PrettyTable.get_html_string

Thank you :)